# Как пользоватся таймером в dll?

Tags: таймер, visual-c++, dll

Создаю `isapi` расширение. Нужно организовать таймер в dll с целью выгрузить не всю библиотеку, а освободить неиспользуемые ресурсы созданные библиотекой.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете гарантировано выгрузить библиотеку только если вы сами загрузили её при помощи `LoadLibrary`, и уверены, что никакой другой код вашего процесса больше не грузил её. В этом случае [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) выгрузит вашу библиотеку.

Учтите, вы должны гарантировать, что никто не пользуется функциями этой библиотеки после выгрузки, иначе проблем не избежать.

Заметьте, что для таймера лучше использовать [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), а не [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx), поскольку `SetTimer` требует наличия message queue.

Comment: точнее вигрузить не всю библиотеку, а освободить неиспользуемые ресурсы созданные бибиотекой.

Comment: эээ... а как несчастная библиотека узнает, использует кто-то её ресурсы или нет? сама библиотека может почистить свои кэши, конечно, но не более.

Comment: библиотеку то я создаю и когда пользователь (много пользователей)обращается к библиотеке она выделяет память под пользовательские данные, а когда пользователь долгое время (все зависит от настроек моего таймера например 10 минут) не обращаеться к библиотеке тогда я удаляю данные пользователя (пишу isapi раcширение для iis сервера на основе odbc драйверов - доступ к любой базе данных в mssqlserver)

Comment: @i_slayer: А, ну так тогда всё просто, это как бы очистка внутреннего кеша.